# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_NativeStripeSdk.default.initialise') while integrating stripe in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments, react-native-stripe-api

I am trying to link stripe payment to a react native cli ecommerce app using the newly launched @stripe/stripe-react-native package but i am getting an error  in android simulator while providing publishable key to stripe provider element

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_NativeStripeSdk.default.initialise')

I tried to integrate the stripe package with another newly created react native cli app with just a normal template but still I am getting the same error. I have also checked the stripe publishable key with a react web app and it is working fine.

Here is my App.js

```
import {StripeProvider} from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <StripeProvider publishableKey="pk_test_51IeDvNS......">
      <View>
        <Text>Hello World...</Text>
      </View>
    </StripeProvider>
  );
};
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
ERROR    TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_NativeStripeSdk.default.initialise')

This error is located at:
    in StripeProvider (at App.js:17)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "amazonclone",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.4",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.7",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.16.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.1.2",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.0.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.0.2",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^5.0.1",
    "country-list": "^2.2.0",
    "country-state-city": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.63",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/country-list": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.64.5",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/zen-observable": "^0.8.2",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

error in android simulator

[image]

call stack in android simulator

[image]

Comment: Are you using Expo? If so you'll need the very latest version that has stripe-react-native support. You can upgrade with `expo install:client:[ios|android]`: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/3#issuecomment-846225534

Comment: No I am not using expo. I am using React native cli. I got some solutions for expo but i haven't got any solution for react native.

Comment: What version of Expo Go are you on?

Comment: I am not using expo, I am using react-native cli

Comment: Can you post your packaje.json to see dependencies' version?

Comment: I have add my package.json file @AlfredoLipari kindly help me.

Comment: @AbhinavJha did you find any solution?

Comment: no i haven't found any solution

Comment: @AbhinavJha hey did you find any solution for the problem yet ?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Error is gone bt rebuilding project